# Scala won't show up in new project - Intellig IDE

Tags: scala, ide

I am moving from Eclipse to IntelliJ but I can't figure this one out. In the new project section, I only find 3 alternatives which aren't mentioned in the documentation, as you see in the picture below, Scala is not found on the right side, what would the problem be?

[Scala new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu1dg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Press "Next", select name and location for project, "Finish" and you'll have an [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) project. Alternatively you can create "IDEA-based Scala project".

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html#create_project

I guess item "Scala" is now "IDEA".